# Any good supplementary text on Algebraic Number Theory?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

I'm going to study algebraic number theory by myself with the following texts:

- *Algebraic Number Theory* by Cassels & Frolich
- *Number Fields* by Daniel Marcus

But I'm not sure whether or not I should use a supplementary text for completeness. I believe I have sufficient background in algebra, as I read Lang's *Algebra*. Yet regarding number theory, the last book which I read is *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland & Rosen. I prefer books with a lot of exercises, and I don't care about the price, since I will read books in library. The following texts are the candidates which I'm considering, and if you think the above two are not enough, could you recommend any of them?

- *Local Fields* by Jean-Pierre Serre
- *Algebraic Theory of Numbers* by P. Samuel
- *Basic number theory* by Weil
- Milne's notes

etc.

Comment: Cassels+Frolich is advanced, Weil is really advanced...

Comment: @lhf Why is it titled “basic” then?